# Is there an Angular 16+, HightChart integration made to update the chart when pivot change the report?

Tags: angular, highcharts, webdatarocks

I'm currently integrating the angular wrapper and using the [app-wdr-pivot](https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/integration-with-angular/) component, also have integrated [HightCharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular) for Angular. Until now I'm not being able to dynamically update the chart when I change something on the pivot.

At this moment the only thing that I could make is recover the pivot reference through the 'ready' EventEmitter.

My `app-wdr-pivot` implementation:

```html
<app-wbr-pivot #pivotTable 
            *ngIf="rowsPopulated" 
            [toolbar]="true" 
            [width]="'100%'" 
            [height]="500"
            [report]="{ dataSource: { data: rows } }" 
            (ready)="pivotChange($event)">
            WebDataRocks will appear here
        </app-wbr-pivot>
```

My `highcharts-chart` implementation:

```html
<highcharts-chart 
            [Highcharts]="Highcharts" 
            [constructorType]="chartConstructor" 
            [options]="chartOptions"
            [(update)]="updateFlag" 
            [oneToOne]="oneToOneFlag" 
            [runOutsideAngular]="runOutsideAngular"
            style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;">
        </highcharts-chart>
```

My `component.ts` values:

```js
@ViewChild('pivotTable') pivotTable: WebdatarocksComponent;
//(Values as integration site example)
columnFilters: any = {};
  selectionType = SelectionType;
  rowSelected = false;
  loadingData = false;
  rowsPopulated: boolean = false

  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts; // required
  chartConstructor: string = 'chart'; // optional string, defaults to 'chart'
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    series: [{
      data: [1, 2, 3],
      type: 'line'
    }],
    title: { text: this.title }
  }; // required
  //chartCallback: Highcharts.ChartCallbackFunction = function (chart) { ... } // optional function, defaults to null
  updateFlag: boolean = false; // optional boolean
  oneToOneFlag: boolean = true; // optional boolean, defaults to false
  runOutsideAngular: boolean = false; // optional boolean, defaults to false
//...MORE IRRELEVANT CODE...
pivotChange($event){
    console.log('(°-°) pivotChange', $event)
  }
```

that last console.log statement throws:

```
addCalculatedMeasure: b => h.vk(b)
addCondition: b => h.ox(b)
clear: () => h.clear()
clearFilter: b => h.vn(b)
closeFieldsList: () => h.Cx()
collapseAllData: () => h.Dx()
collapseData: b => h.rp(b)
connectTo: b => h.zr(b)
customizeCell: b => h.LW(b)
dispose: () => { h.la(); }
expandAllData: (b = !0) => h.Ux(b)
expandData: b => h.xp(b)
exportTo: (b, a = null, c = null) => h.Aj(b, a, c)
getAllConditions: () => h.yD()
getAllHierarchies: () => h.Gu()
getAllMeasures: () => h.Gn()
getCell: (b, a) => h.Ld(b, a)
getColumns: () => h.Ku()
getCondition: b => h.ED(b)
getData: (b, a, c) => h.getData(b, a, c)
getFilter: b => h.ID(b)
getFilterProperties: b => h.JD(b)
getFormat: b => h.Ne(b)
getMeasures: () => h.Pu()
getMembers: (b, a, c) => h.Ay(b, a, c)
getOptions: () => h.Cp()
getReport: b => h.Dp(b)
getReportFilters: () => h.Qu()
getRows: () => h.Ru()
getSelectedCell: () => h.Su()
getSort: b => h.PD(b)
load: b => h.load(b)
off: (b, a) => h.E_(b, a)
on: (b, a) => h.TN(b, a)
open: () => h.open()
openFieldsList: () => h.nv()
print: (b = null) => h.print(b)
refresh: () => h.refresh()
removeAllCalculatedMeasures: () => h.eq()
removeAllConditions: () => h.Jz()
removeCalculatedMeasure: b => h.fo(b)
removeCondition: b => h.Kz(b)
removeSelection: () => h.ws()
replaceHierarchyCaption: b => h.Lz(b)
runQuery: b => h.Qz(b)
save: (b = { filename: "report.json" }, a = null, c = null, e = null, g = !1) => {…}
setBottomX: (b, a, c) => h.uv(b, a, c)
setFilter: (b, a, c = !1) => h.wv(b, a, c)
setFormat: (b, a) => h.jq(b, a)
setOptions: b => h.Uj(b)
setReport: b => h.xv(b)
setSelectedCell: (b, a) => h.Is(b, a)
setSort: (b, a) => h.jo(b, a)
setTopX: (b, a, c) => h.zv(b, a, c)
sortValues: (b, a, c, e) => h.dA(b, a, c, e)
updateData: (b, a) => h.dl(b, a)
version: "Version 1.4.14"
```

and finally my specific problem is how to get the data currently represented in the pivot to update the chart through the reference to `chartOptions`.
If there anione with a similar project or some kind of example it will be awesome. I apologise in advance for spelling/grammar errors, this isn't my native tongue.

Comment: Please provide a code example to help others understand your exact problem. Also, there are many spelling errors.

Comment: Could you please once again explain what is your main problem? Do you struggle with getting the data or updating the Highcharts component?

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work, get the data from the pivot and update the chart, this is how:
On the WDR Pivot you should use the @Output update like this

```
<app-wbr-pivot #pivotTable 
            *ngIf="rowsPopulated" 
            [toolbar]="true" 
            [width]="'100%'" 
            [height]="500"
            [report]="{ dataSource: { data: rows } }"
            (update)="pivotChange()">
            WebDataRocks will appear here
        </app-wbr-pivot>
```

and in your pivotChange() method do:

```
pivotChange() {
    let data = this.pivotTable.webDataRocks.getData({}, (data) => {
      let simplifyedData = data.data.map(item => item['v0'])
      this.chartOptions.series[0] = {
        type: 'line',
        data: simplifyedData
      }
      this.updateFlag = true
    })
  }
```

change updateFlag to true is the key to update HighCharts. Hopefully this will help someone :).

Comment: If your pivot values have no sense, neither will be the chart obviously